# Wordpress plugin contact form 7 error messages

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP contact form 7 plugin. I want to customize the error messages rendering order. Because the error message are seems to be displaying with irrelevant fields.

[image]

Below is the generated HTML for each field:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
    <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid contact-input" aria-required="true" placeholder="Name">
    <span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip-no-ajax">Please fill the required field.</span>
</span>
```

I want the HTML to be rendered as: span before input.

With in the plugin controller.php i customized this ,

```
'into' => 'span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.' . $name,
'message' => $reason );
```

I placed reason before but didn't worked.

Similarly within the classes.php,

```
$ve = '<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip-no-ajax">' . esc_html( $ve ) . '</span>';
        return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_validation_error', $ve, $name, $this );
```

I applied the filters before span but didn't worked.

So, my question is how to show error messages on top of their respective input fields. CSS tips are not highly appreciated.

NOTE: We have responsive layout.

Comment: You can do it with css, no need to dig into the core plugin

Comment: How..? please let me know but it should not effect our responsiveness.

Comment: Just set the position of the displayed error, you can check it with firebug and just change the position. Sorry, but I don't have idea of your theme but it is easy and it's not effect on responsiveness